# Well pump runs 15 seconds then off for 105 seconds until pressure is full.

Tags: water, water-pressure, pump, well

Well is 165 feet deep according to county records. Well pump is approximately 100 feet deep (string and plumb bob so it's approximate at best). New pressure switch 40/60. Tank drained and aired up to 38 lbs. We have had no problems over the 4 years owning this home until now. The pump, when using water hoses out side, has begun "short cycling" (?). On a consistent basis it runs for 15 seconds then turns off for 105 seconds. I've metered the wires in, at the well casing, and the demand power stays at 240 until the pressure is satisfied. The pump will continually run for 15 seconds and off for 105 seconds until the switch turns off. We have not noticed any issues with just the in house use. It's only since the I opened the outside lines this summer. One problem I did see, there is are two wire nuts about 18 inches down inside the well casing. While metering the voltage and timing the cycles, for a few hours, one of these lines shorted against the case a few times causing a loud pop and tripping the 220 breaker.  I have yet been able to figure out how to get down in there to properly repair them.  This has been an incredible system, any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Since your line going down is staying hot (turned on) when the pump stops, but later shuts off when pressure is eventually reached there is really only a couple  possibilities—the pump is overheating in 15 seconds of run time, and cooling off enough to repeat the cycle in 105 seconds -or- the water tables low and it’s starved for water to pump.  I’m surprised that with only pumping 13% of the time you ever can get up to full pressure.

Comment: Tyson, thank you for the reply. Both those scenarios have crossed my mind and really worry me. With just my wife and I still here we really don't use a tremendous amount of water so we haven't noticed any problems. We live in a great water area ... Twin Lakes Ohio (lolz) less than 100 yards from a lake!  It mainly started while using the hose, liberally, outside. I'm thinking of sticking the hose down the well and turning it on to see if it is a water issue by feeding it back to the pump.

Comment: I'm just hesitant because I don't want to churn up any mess at the bottom, adding to the dilemma! It's beginning to look like an upcoming out of the budget expense. Thanks again for the assist. Will post again when I figure something out.